# How to only print a line if a blank line follows

Tags: sed, text-processing

From some program, I get output of the form

```
aaaaa
bbbbb

ccccc
ddddd
eeeee
fffff

ggggg
hhhhh
iiiii
```

including the final blank line.

I want to get only the last lines of each block, i.e. every line followed by a blank line:

```
bbbbb
fffff
iiiii
```

I tried with `sed` and checked (as usual) the [sed1liners](http://www.catonmat.net/blog/wp-content/uploads/2008/09/sed1line.txt), but could not come up with something useful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to play with the `hold space`.

```
sed -ne '/^$/ { g; p; b }; h; $ { g; p }' infile
```

How does it work?

For each normal line, copy it to `hold space` (`h`) overwritting previous content. And for special cases (empty lines and last line of file), take the content of hold space and print it.

It yields:

```
bbbbb
fffff
iiiii
```

Answer (score 3):

with awk:

```
awk '
    /^[[:blank:]]*$/ {print prev} 
    {prev=$0}
    END {if (length(prev)) print prev}
'
```

Comment: This solution will need an `END` block to handle the case of last input line. Currently it doesn't print it.

Answer (score 2):

With `awk`:

```
$ awk '!$0{print a} {a=$0}' file
bbbbb
fffff
```

- `!$0{print a}` if the line is empty, print the stored line `a`.
- `{a=$0}` store the line in the variable `a`.

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed '$!N;/.\n$/P;D' file
```

Comment: You should add `/\n/! p` just before the `D` (or something similar) for the special case of last input line where `N` won't match and neither a newline as last character.